# Crystal reports - suppress heading on current page if not enough room for detail lines

Tags: crystal-reports, heading, suppress

I have a report with various header sections and can grow as needed. 
My problem is that just before my details section is a header that prints the column headings for the details to follow. I am trying to figure out how to stop this header from printing if there is not enough room for at least one detail line under it. (First page is almost filled with heading information).

It is causing the column headings to be printed on the bottom of page 1 with no details below it and then printing the column headings again on page 2 with details following properly.
I have tried various functions to try and stop it all without luck.
Thanks
Peter

Comment: Can you add a MRE? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You may try to transform the details section and the column headers into a subreport. Then put the subreport in the most inner header. Leave the details section empty. Then check the subreport as keep together. I'm not sure if it will work, but give it a try (i can't teste it right now, sorry).